# Stop current process of loop when null value and continue with next value

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Now when `as[i].getUser() = null`, the program stops with `NullPointerException`.  But what I want is to stop the current process of the loop only and *continue* with next value, the best will be **from the method `convertUser()`** since it's used in many places. I know that catching the `NullPointerException` is not recommended.

```
public Project[] convertProjects(){
    ProjectR[] as = getProjects();
    Project[] bs = new Project[a.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < as.length; i++){
        Project b = new Project();
        b.setName(as[i].getNameR());
        b.setUser(convertUser(as[i].getUserR()));
        b.setCenter(convertCenter(as[i].getCenterR()));
        bs[i]=b;
    }
    return bs;
 }
private Center convertCenter(CenterR centerR) {
    Center centerL = new Center();
    centerL.setManager(convertUser(centerR.getUser()));
    centerL.setName(centerR.getName());
    centerL.setResID(centerR.getID());
    return centerL;
}

private User convertUser(UserR uR) {
    User userL = new PFPWSUser();
    userL.setID(uR.getID());
    userL.setFirstName(uR.getFirstName());
    userL.setLastName(uR.getLastName());
    userL.setEmail(uR.getEmail());
    return userL;
}
```

Comment: Better user exception handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these two lines

```
    as[i] == null
    continue;
    b.setUser(convertUser(as[i].getUserR()));
```

inside your convertProjects Method

Answer (score 1):

Check if `as[i].getUserR()` is null before using it:

```
if(as[i].getUserR() != null) { // Can use since not null
    b.setUser(convertUser(as[i].getUserR()));
}
```

Since no null values are used, the NullPointerException wont be thrown and the loop will continue.

Answer (score 1):

insert checking element as[i] for null

```
if (as[i]==null) continue;
```

at start of for{} block